# custom routing for podman rootless containers

Tags: podman

I want to route all traffic coming from a Podman container to a specified gateway. I can easily achieve this with a tap device. However, when running Podman in rootless mode, I can see the tap device inside the container but not on the host (where I would implement the routing).

Is there any way to specify which interface Podman traffic arrives on the host?

Additionally, I want to do this on a per-container basis, meaning a different interface for each container. In the case of grouping multiple containers inside a pod, I want to perform this configuration only once for the pod.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a non-root user isn't able to create interfaces on the host. A `tap` device is a virtual device that is connected to an application -- in the case of Podman, this application is `slirp4netns`, which is described [here](https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns).

This is all to say that there is no "interface on the host" -- traffic from the rootless container flows into `slirp4netns`, which is then responsible for forwarding traffic to remote destinations.

Published ports are handled by the [rootlessport](https://github.com/containers/podman/tree/main/cmd/rootlessport) process.

This is very different from the configuration used by Podman when running as `root` (in which case it uses `veth` interfaces to connect containers to host bridges and netfilter rules to handle port publishing).

If you want to set up custom routing, you probably want to run Podman as `root`.

Comment: I do require root privileges anyway to configure routing on the host. I could easily just create an interface on the host (per container) and pass this to a container without root privileges. Is this possible with `slirp4netns`?

Comment: You can certainly place an interface into a namespace if you have `root` privileges; `slirp4nets` doesn't really enter the picture in that case. But if you require `root` access in the first place to configure routing, why not just run Podman as `root` as well?

Comment: The idea here was not to avoid root everywhere, but to minimize its use. Using root upfront to set up interfaces, bridges, routes, .. on the host can be acceptable. If a rootless podman container can use those - even better as I can avoid one more root process (podman in this case). If I am not reasonably able to create such a setup with rootless podman, then I will have to look at different approaches.